# hyperlinks in phpmyadmin

Tags: excel, phpmyadmin

I have an excel spreadsheet, with one of the columns in form of hyperlinks which when clicked opens a particular web page which is not stored on my computer. How do I import these hyperlinks into phpMyAdmin and make them clickable? The import function creates text which is not clickable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the links clickable. MySQL stores only plain text.

However, you could create a web page that displays the data from the database (this is the normal reason for using MySQL) and automatically makes URLs hyperlinked, but you would need PHP or another server-side language.

In theory you could add that functionality to phpMyAdmin, but it's a brave man who tries to find his way through PMA's mess of code. :p

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe you can. MySQL has no concept of "clickable links" and thus neither does phpmyadmin.